# Function to calculate the round trip communication time of Voyager 1

Tags: time, communication, roundtrip

'''
Hi there

I trying to find a simple function that I can use to estimate the round trip communication time of the Voyager 1 Space craft (1, 3 10 100 or 300 years from now).

This is the information that I have so far, it should be a simple function and I understand the math. Just need the language.

Thanks

```
import time

def communication_time(days):

    distance_start = 0
    distance_now = 22944706739.083 #in km
    velocity_voy_1 = 16.9995 # in km/s
    speed_of_light = 299792 # km/s


distance = distance_start + velocity_voy_1 * time_since_start

round_trip_communication_time = (2 * distance_now/speed_of_light)

return 0

    print(abs(communication_time(0) - 146143.0) < 10)
    print(abs(communication_time(55) - 146682.0) < 10)
    print(abs(communication_time(365.25 * 6) - 167616.0) < 10)
```

Comment: What is the language? Btw I dont think V1 is that far away.

Comment: Python 3, sorry for the omission

Comment: There are 24*3600 seconds in a day... `distance_now` is not used... since it's from *now*, calculate `distance = distance_now+v * days_converted_to_seconds`  and use `distance` in rtc_time, then return that rtc_time.

Comment: Actually, @Breakingnotsobad, is IS that far away.

Comment: Oh yeah... I read km while it was miles... Forgot that some people still use these middle-age units...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are after:

```
import time

distance_now = 22944706739.083 #in km
velocity_voy_1 = 16.9995 # in km/s
speed_of_light = 299792 # km/s

def where_will_voyager_be( days ):
    return distance_now + velocity_voy_1 * 86400 * days

def communication_time( distance ):
    return 2 * distance / speed_of_light

def comm_time_in_days( days ):
    dist = where_will_voyager_be( days )
    return communication_time( dist )

# How long is comm time now?

print( "Now:", comm_time_in_days(0), "s" )
print( "Next month:", comm_time_in_days(30), "s" )
print( "Next year:", comm_time_in_days(365.25), "s" )
print( "5 years:", comm_time_in_days(5 * 365.25), "s" )
print( "10 years:", comm_time_in_days(10 * 365.25), "s" )
print( "30 years:", comm_time_in_days(30 * 365.25), "s" )
```

Output:

```
Now: 153070.84071011236 s
Next month: 153364.79587902947 s
Next year: 156649.74489167825 s
5 years: 170965.3616179418 s
10 years: 188859.88252577122 s
30 years: 260437.96615708893 s
```

Comment: can you advise me as to why the following print statements would have been included in the original question.                                                              print(abs(communication_time(0) - 146143.0) < 10)
    print(abs(communication_time(55) - 146682.0) < 10)
    print(abs(communication_time(365.25 * 6) - 167616.0) < 10)

Comment: The required out was *True   True   True?

Comment: You didn't mention that you had other requirements.  You just said you needed the number.  Those statements are apparently validating your homework, checking that you got the right answer.  However, the numbers don't line up.  With the numbers you gave, (0) is 153070, not 146173.  That's a difference of a billion km.